# Lambda reinitialize vector - why does it work?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Why does the following compile?

```
vector<int> vec;

auto lambda = [ vec (move(vec)) ]() {  //??      
};
```

How can I re-initialize an already assigned vec variable with `vec (move(vec))` ? Doesn't this call the move constructor?

If I write:

```
vector<int> vec;
vec (move(vec));
```

this is not valid

Comment: In msvc2013 you can't do it. What compiler do you use?

Comment: (When two compilers say different things on standard code, nearly always MSVC is wrong and GCC right)

Comment: `vec(move(vec))` is equivalent to `vec.operator()(move(vec))`. May be you meant move construction: `vector<int> v2(move(vec));` or move assignment: `v2 = move(vec)`?

Comment: @myaut it is in the last snippet I wrote, it is a move construction in the first (from what I got from the answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a change that did not make it into C++11 but C++14, we can see the rationale from [N3610](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3610.html):

> C++11 lambdas do not support capture-by-move. There has been at least two rejected NB comments on this for C++11, the first one was JP9 on CD1, the second was FI8 on FCD. FI8 refers to a Core reflector message by Roshan Naik, where Roshan explains that it would be very useful to be able to move-capture containers and other objects that are expensive to copy. Furthermore, move-only types like iostreams (especially stringstreams) and unique_ptrs can't be captured without wrapping them. This lack of cooperation between move semantics and lambdas was briefly discussed in the Evolution Working Group in Portland 2012 as one of potential extensions that would "complete C++11". Unfortunately, scheduling conflicts and lack of time has prevented producing a wording proposal for such an extension; this paper tries to explain the intended design

and the wording was introduced by [N3648](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3648.html):

> For every init-capture a non-static data member named by the
>   identifier of the init-capture is declared in the closure type. This
>   member is not a bit-field and not mutable. The type of that member
>   corresponds to the type of a hypothetical variable declaration of the
>   form "auto init-capture ;", except that the variable name (i.e., the
>   identifier of the init-capture) is replaced by a unique identifier. [
>   Note: This enables an init-capture like "x = std::move(x)"; the second
>   "x" must bind to a declaration in the surrounding context. --end note
>   ] No entity is captured by an init-capture. Within the
>   lambda-expression's lambda-declarator and compound-statement, the
>   identifier in the init-capture hides any declaration of the same name
>   in scopes enclosing the lambda-expression. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 4;
> auto y = [&r = x, x = x+1]()->int {
>             r += 2;
>             return x+2;
>          }();  // Updates ::x to 6, and initializes y to 7.
> ```
>
> --end example]

The wording changes in the draft C++14 standard [N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf), although it looks like formatting and clean-up.

Answer (score 5):

This is called an *init-capture*. It declaration of a new variable that shadows the above `vec`. It's used to capture move-only types in lambda expressions:

> An *init-capture* behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “`auto init-capture ;`”
>   whose declarative region is the lambda-expression’s compound-statement, [..]

More info on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Comment: Interesting.. who owns the resources when the lambda is called? I suppose only the lambda-captured variable (since the other has its data moved), right?

Comment: @Albert `vec` was moved into the the init-capture whose lifetime is bound by the declarative region of the lambda, so it is the lambda that now owns the resource.